# Facebook shared video using opengraph: video does not play on mobile

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

If i try to share video using custom action, i can correctly see the video in FB Desktop, but it does not play (touch does not make anything) in smartphone and tablet.

My code for FB OpenGraph is:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://PATH_TO.jpg">
   <meta property="og:url" content="http://PATH_TO_PLAYRER>
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="IntervYou">
   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="478556705688305">
   <meta property="og:type" content="MY_CUSTOM_OPENGRAPH_ACTION" />
   <meta property="og:title" content="Titolo">
   <meta property="og:image:width" content="360">
   <meta property="og:image:height" content="360">
   <meta property="og:video:width" content="360">
   <meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
   <meta property="og:description" content="desc">
   <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
   <meta property="og:video" content="https://PATH_TO.mp4">
   <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://PATH_TO.mp4">
   </head>
   </html>
```

How can i make it play also in mobile?